# Name of Noether Normalization lemma

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra

The theorem states

> Let $A$ be a finitely generated $K$-algebra. Then there is a finite algebraically independent set S over $K$ and A is finite over $K[S]$.

I have seen some algebraic geometric interpretation. But can I understand just from aglebraic point of view? (Why is it called normalization?)

A normal domain $R$ is an integral domain which is integrally closed as for the ring morphism $R\hookrightarrow\text{Frac}(R)$. Can I use the theorem to normalize $R$ in its fraction field or something?

Comment: The word normalization is not meant to be interpreted as normalization in the algebraic sense. Sure $A$ is integeral over $K[S]$ but the true essence of the lemma lies in its geometric interpretation which is beautifully explained in Gathmann's lecture notes on commutative algebra https://www.mathematik.uni-kl.de/~gathmann/class/commalg-2013/commalg-2013.pdf [Example 9.4, 10.1]. You can see from the example in his notes, that after doing a linear coordinate change, the corresponding map of varieties is normalized in the sense that the fiber over each point is finite and non-empty.

Comment: Also, an integral element satisfies a monic polynomial relation. So after doing the linear coordinate change the leading coefficient of polynomial defining the variety is $1$ (normalized).